# Button Inside a grid value is not returning updated value onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, grid

I have a `Button` inside an `ItemTemplate` in a grid. I'm assigning the button text dynamically. Since I need to have different text for each row button. But `OnClick` event is not showing the updated text instead it is showing a empty string. Please help!!

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GetHistory">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button 
            DataField="GetHistory" 
            ID="btn_getHistory" 
            CausesValidation="false" 
            runat="server" 
            OnClick="btn_getHistory_Click" Visible="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>




  protected void btn_getHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //My sender text is showing empty here
    }


  protected void GridViewTree1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.DataItem != null && !((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataItem)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString().Contains("\\"))
            {

                Button btn_getHistory = (Button)e.Row.Cells[3].FindControl("btn_getHistory");
                if (btn_getHistory != null)
                {
                    btn_getHistory.Visible = true;

                    var chunks = ((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataItem)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString().Split('_'); // any separator characters
                    var a = chunks.Take(chunks.Length - 1);
                    string testsetName = string.Empty;
                    foreach (string b in a)
                    {
                        testsetName = testsetName + b + '_';
                    }


                    btn_getHistory.Text = testsetName.ToString().TrimEnd('_');
                }
   }
```

Comment: Maybe because it is Visible="false"

Comment: I'm setting the visibility to true and then assigning the value for each row

Comment: Where is that code?

Comment: Grid should have some kind of `OnitemDataBound` event, where you can modify the value of button at each row, or you could use some kind of databinding. It will be better if you could show grid code and back-end code.

Comment: I have placed Rowcreated event as well where i'm updating the button value.Pls help